# $\underset{y \in D }{\max}{( \lim_{x\to a} f(x,y))}=\lim_{x\to a} \underset{y \in D }{\max}f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ is continuous function in domain $D$ .Is it possible to write this equality below ?  is it true ? or  Do we need any condition to write it if it is true ? Thank u in advance.

$\underset{y \in D }{\max}{( \lim_{x\to a} f(x,y))}=\lim_{x\to a}( \underset{y \in D }{\max}f(x,y))$

Comment: You are asking if the function $\psi (x) = \max_{y \in D} f(x,y)$ is continuous at $x=a$. It is true that $\psi$ is lower semi continuous, but you need additional conditions (such a compactness) on $D$ to ensure that $\psi$ is also upper semi continuous.

Comment: sorry we assume that  $D$ is compact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $D$ is compact and $f$ continuous. Define $\psi(x) = \max_{y \in D} f(x,y)$.

Note that you are trying to show that $\lim_{x \to a} \psi(x) = \lim_{x \to a} (\max_{y \in D} f(x,y)) =\max_{y \in D} f(a,y) = \psi(a)$.

Suppose $x_n \to x$ and fix $y$. Then $\psi(x_n) \ge f(x_n,y)$ for all $n$.
Then $\liminf_n \psi(x_n) \ge f(x,y)$. Since this is true for all $y\in D$, we
have $\liminf_n \psi(x_n) \ge \psi(x)$. Hence $\psi$ is lower semi continuous.
Note that this is true for any $D$ (and is true if you replace $\max$ by
$\sup$).

Now choose  a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\psi(x_{n_k}) \to \limsup_n \psi(x_n)$. To simplify notation, let $z_k = x_{n_k}$.

Now choose $y_{n} \in D$ such that $\psi(z_{n}) = f(z_{n},y_{n})$, and choose a subsequence $y_{n_k}$ that converges to some $\bar{y}$, then we have
$\psi(z_{n_k}) = f(z_{n_k},y_{n_k})  \to f(x,\bar{y})$, and so
$\limsup_n \psi(x_n) = \lim_k \psi(z_{n_k}) = f(x,\bar{y}) \le \psi(x)$, and
we see that $\psi$ is upper semi continuous.

Hence $\psi$ is continuous.

**Aside**: Here is an example that shows that $\psi$ is not necessarily upper semi continuous:

Let $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \max ( 1 - |y-{1 \over x}|,0), & x \neq 0\\
0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$, and let $D = \mathbb{R}$ (which is not compact, or course).

Then $\psi(x) = 1$ for $x \neq 0$, but $\psi(0) = 0$.

Comment: if $\psi$ is continuous can we say that both of them equal ?                       $\underset{y \in D }{\max}{( \lim_{x\to a} f(x,y))}=\lim_{x\to a}( \underset{y \in D }{\max}f(x,y))$

Comment: Yes, then $\lim_{x \to a} \psi(x) = \psi(a)$. Expanding the definition of $\psi$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Can we expand this for all domain $D$? you already have given the answer.Thank you

Comment: I added an example showing that it is not necessarily true if $D$ is not compact.